# How to add a prefix “#” to lines that contain string “000” in all files in a directory and its sub-directories in linux?

Tags: linux

This is a 000 line.
This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line.
If I run the command, it should add # to the front of any lines where "000" was found. The result would be this:

```
#This is a 000 line.
#This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line.
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome! It would be nice if you could also let us know what you have tried and didn't work so we can help you find out why it doesn't work. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section on how to improve you question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
find yourdir -type f -exec sed -i '/000/s/^/#/' {} \;
```

Where `find` searches `yourdir` (and all its subdir) for files (`-type f`, `f` stands for file, `d` would stand for directory); this is done without any other requirement on the files.

Then it `-exec`utes the `sed` command on each of these files (`{}` is the current file being processed by `-exec`): the edit consists in acting only on the lines mathcing `000`, and applying the `s` command to such lines; the `s`ubstitute command will change each beginning of line (`^`, which is not a character, but just an anchor) to `#` (in fact `#` is inserted at the beginning of such lines).

<s>But there's a simpler `sed` command to prepend things which doesn't come to mi mind.</s> I was thinking about the `i` and `a` commands, but they actually insert/append a new line.

Besides, I'm using the `-i` option which is not POSIX.